# How to prevent Wordpress loading external resources when developing

Tags: localhost

As I'm developing my new web site on a local machine while commuting (with limited connectity), I wonder if there is any option to avoid WP loading any external bit.

In fact, all scripts like google fonts, gravatar, are making my page saving / editing activity terribly slow.

Is there any options I can set?
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [Airplane Mode](https://github.com/norcross/airplane-mode)?

Comment: Airplane Mode is the best thing since Betty White.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't have an option for restricting external content from loading in the browser.

Some resources such as fonts, or external scripts, can always be saved in the web root and served directly from there.

For resources that you cannot store locally (Gravatar images for example) you could consider Charles Proxy. Charles Proxy is a great application for debugging and shaping HTTP traffic. One of it's many features includes Remote Mapping which would allow you to capture your external requests and serve a local fallback instead.

[Charles Proxy - Map Remote](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-remote/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what type of machine you use,  what browser,  and if it had to be WordPress.  If you want to stick with WordPress solution use  tocshos suggestion.  If you don't care there are probably better alternatives. What you're looking for really is just a domain ip mapping or firewall program or host editor.  Charles Proxy  does work well.  If you have a mac you can try out little snitch or tcp block. I'm sure there are windows alternatives. You might also find it even easier to just install a browser extension. A good host editor for Firefox is hostsadmin. However check out https://disconnect.me is probably the easiest and fastest thing out there to use.